# Show sum involving sines is non-negative

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I want to show that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{k \geq 1 \\ k \text{ odd}}} k e^{-k^2 a} \sin(kx)  \geq 0 \qquad \text{for all } x \in [0,\pi], \, a > 0.
\end{equation}

How should I start?  I tried approximating the infinite sum by its partial sums, but the terms oscillate and the number of terms needed for a good enough approximation increases without bound as $a \to 0$.  Perhaps somebody can recognize this function as the Fourier series (?) of some better-known function, or provide some inequalities for dealing with such series that I am not aware of.